# Get distinct values from a table but select the most recent in case of duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a PostgreSQL have the table `Sales` containing the following data:

```
| id(PK) | eva_dts_id(FK) | realm_name | device_id | timestamp | product_id | product_name | quantity | product_price | revenue |
```

`realm_name` and `device_id` are **constants** and even if they changed in the future they would be updated accordingly on this table.

I'm trying to create the view `Products` on it with the following schema:

```
| realm_name | device_id | product_id | product_name | product_price |
```

So far I used the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT realm_name, device_id, product_id, product_name, product_price
FROM public.Sales;
```

This works assuming the product list of a device is immutable and so won't change in the future. I'd like to release that assumption and create a product list data for a device considering always the **most recent** record (based on the `timestamp` found on the `Sales` table). So for instance if I have the product "Chocomilk" that had the records:

```
| id(PK) | eva_dts_id(FK) | realm_name | device_id | timestamp | product_id | product_name | quantity | product_price | revenue |
"03ef91f6-bb24-4c8e-90ef-366cc4dee5a6"  "e853dcec-c369-4111-816d-1645067df8e1"  "tenant"    "RbbMIyemWTOI99N6XZx1hA"    "2023-03-26 22:43:31.454734"    "10"    "Chocomilk" 1   0.38    0
"03ef91f6-bb24-4c8e-90ef-366cc4dee5a6"  "e853dcec-c369-4111-816d-1645067df8e1"  "tenant"    "RbbMIyemWTOI99N6XZx1hA"    "2023-04-12 22:43:31.454734"    "10"    "Chocomilk" 1   2.3 0
"03ef91f6-bb24-4c8e-90ef-366cc4dee5a6"  "e853dcec-c369-4111-816d-1645067df8e1"  "tenant"    "RbbMIyemWTOI99N6XZx1hA"    "2023-05-18 22:43:31.454734"    "10"    "Chocomilk" 1   1.5 0
```

I would consider the last record only.

How can I rewrite the view query in order to achieve this?

Comment: Just search for 'select the most recent entries'; there are lots of examples.

Comment: Lateral or cross apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to order your items information by timestamp and get only newest. Something along the lines of

```sql
select
    realm_name,
    device_id,
    product_id,
    product_name,
    product_price
from
    (
        SELECT
            realm_name,
            device_id,
            product_id,
            product_name,
            product_price,
            row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    realm_name,
                    device_id,
                    product_id
                ORDER BY
                    timestamp desc
            ) rn
        FROM
            public.Sales
    ) as most_recents
where
    rn = 1;
```

Check carefully `PARTITION BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()` to contain unique identifiers of item, that don't change over time.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine. I proposed an alternative a bit more concise. Do you think they tackle all the same use cases?

Comment: @Barnercart, yes result will be identical.

Comment: I think you should remove the device_id from the PARTITION BY. If it changes this query will give you duplicates, not the latest

Comment: @tinazmu, I tried to guess fields to use in partition. Since semantics of data in columns it's not quite clear and what field are considered constant for item is not specified, I added notification about partition by clause to my answer. The idea that I guessed more or less correctly is supported by answer of OP, containing same fields as identifiers of items.

Comment: Apologies @markalex, you are right; we should leave it to OP to select the partitioning logic.

Comment: You are right, I didn't specified. The columns `realm_name` and `device_id` are indeed constants. And even if they changed in the future the old values would be updated accordingly I guess. I updated the question just to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Proposing myself an alternative solution to @markalex 's answer and following the advice of @tinazmu :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT realm_name,
                device_id,
                product_id,
                product_name,
                product_price
FROM public.Sales AS ext
WHERE timestamp =
    (
      SELECT MAX(int.timestamp)
      FROM public.Sales AS int
      WHERE int.realm_name = ext.realm_name
       AND int.device_id = ext.device_id
       AND int.product_id = ext.product_id
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres offers another option: [Distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) clause of select statement. This clause results in keeping on the first row matching the distinct on expression (according to the order by phrase). What you are looking for is: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CqDXdb0p))

```
select distinct on(product_name) *
  from sales 
 order by product_name, sale_ts desc;
```

Note: IMHO naming a column `timestamp` is poor practice as it is a SQL reserved word and a Postgres data type (although not Postgres reserved). I have substituted `sale_ts` in above and demo.

Comment: This is the most proper solution for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a common table expression for queries like this, it makes it easier to identify what the data is and how you are filtering it.

Row_number and partition, give the query engine a better idea of what you are actually after. Sql is a declarative language, whenever possible you should describe what you want, not do tricks to lead it to the right answer.

```sql
;with cte as (
select  realm_name
      , device_id
      , product_id
      , product_name
      , product_price
      , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY realm_name, device_id, product_id
                           ORDER BY timestamp desc
                          ) rw
from public.Sales
)
select realm_name
      , device_id
      , product_id
      , product_name
      , product_price
from cte 
where rw=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (might be more intuitive) is to filter out older records using EXISTS function:

```
SELECT  T.realm_name,
        T.device_id,
        T.product_id,
        T.product_name,
        T.product_price
FROM    Sales       AS  T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Sales               AS  newer
            WHERE   newer.product_id    =   T.product_id
            AND     newer.[timestamp]   >   T.[timestamp]
        )
```

This query will make sure there isn't any newer record for the same product_id